# JS: Does await have to bubble up?

Tags: javascript

I am already awaiting my api call within `shouldUseSpecial`.  When I use that method, does that have to be `awaited` as well within myMainFunc?

```
function myMainFunc() { 

        const request = new ServiceRequest()

        request.addInput("params", {
            use_special: shouldUseSpecial(),
        });

        return request;
}


async function shouldUseSpecial() {
     const resolvedCall = await fetch(//myapi);

     return resolvedCall.data.trial;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Your function shouldUseSpecial is async so it means that the result should be awaited.

Otherwise, you will get a promise and not the result you are expecting.

Comment: Minor caveat: You can use [Promise].then(function) instead if you calling from a non-async function. But otherwise this answer is correct